# regular expression for password for special character

Tags: javascript

I need to modify below regular expression with special character allowed.

```
<input type="password" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$" required/>
```

Comment: `special character allowed.` which special characters ?

Comment: I would just change the last part from `[A-Za-z\d]{8,}` to `.{8,}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added both allowing all special characters and only specific characters

All characters:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$
```

Specific characters:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d$&+,:;=?@#|^*()%!-_]{8,}$
```